# How to remove __proto__ property from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following function based on Node-Express:

```
//function on server side
app.get('/loginCheck', loggedCheck, function(req, res) {
    var data = {local: {}, facebook: {}};
    data.id = req.user._id;
    data.local.email = req.user.local.email;
    data.local.fname = req.user.local.fname;
    data.local.lname = req.user.local.lname ;
    data.local.college = req.user.local.college ;
    data.local.degree = req.user.local.degree ;
    data.year = req.user.year ;
    data.mobile = req.user.mobile ;
    data.city = req.user.city ;
    data.facebook.id = req.user.facebook.id ;
    //res.json(data);        

    var x = {};
    x.name = "someName"

    res.json(x);
})
```

Following is the code on client side which makes an ajax requests:

```
//function on client side making an ajax request
$.get("/loginCheck",function(data,status){
    console.log(data);
});
```

In the former code on server side, `req.user` is a mongodb object created by mongoose. What I want to do is send the data object (which has some selected attributes of `req.user` object) and send the object as JSON as response.

The variable `x` is a custom created variable.

The problem is: 
When I send the `data` object to client, `__proto__` attribute is also added with the object which is not happening when I am sending `x` to the client.
But, I don't want the `__proto__` in the client side, because, from some articles, I found that there are security issues with `__proto__`.

I need help on how to remove `__proto__` from the `data` object.

Comment: You cannot remove `__proto__`, an internal property.

Comment: @BhojendraSah: `.__proto__` is not an internal property, but one inherited from `Object.prototype`

Comment: Security issues? No, you must have misread that. Can you point us to those articles?

Comment: `res.json` will not include the `__proto__` property. Are you sure you're seeing it in the actual HTTP response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remove that. It doesn't cause any trouble/problem.

You can use like this.

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    console.log(k, v);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can forego a prototype on an object simply by using `Object.create(null)` and defining the properties you wish to use.

```
var obj = Object.create(null);

Object.defineProperty(obj, {
  'foo': {
    value: 1,
    enumerable: true,

  },
  'bar': {
    value: 2,
    enumerable: false
  }
});

// or...

obj.foo = 1
obj.bar = 2

/* various checks */

obj instanceof Object; // false
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj); // false
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj); // null
obj + ""; // TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
'toString' in obj; // false
foo; // 1
obj['bar']; // 2
JSON.stringify(obj); // {"foo":1}
{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'foo'); // true
{}.propertyIsEnumerable.call(obj, 'bar'); // false
```

And in this approach, you no longer need to check for `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`

```
for (var key in obj) {
  // do something
}
```

Read More: [True Hash Maps in JavaScript](http://ryanmorr.com/true-hash-maps-in-javascript/)

MDN: 
[Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) &
[Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```js
// with __proto__

var obj = {} // equivalent to Object.create(Object.prototype);
obj.key = 'value'

console.log(obj)



// without __proto__

var bareObj = Object.create(null)
Object.defineProperty(bareObj, {
  'key': {
    value: 'value',
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  }
})
// or... bareObj.key = 'value'

console.log(bareObj)
```

Comment: OP seems to be sending and parsing JSON, where you don't really have the choice. And none of us can even reproduce the problem.

Comment: OP could map his JSON to the bare object then parse it: `Object.keys(obj).map(key => bareObj[key] = obj[key])` or `Object.assign(bareObj, obj)`. Alas, this is old, but wanted to show it can be done for others that stumble upon it.

Comment: This doesn't stop `__proto__` from invoking special behaviour when assigned. Whatever is assigned to `__proto__` is set as the prototype even if it never had one before.

Comment: Agreed with @jgmjgm. Although creating your own objects seem decent, this still does not solve the issue when you are deserializing an object, especially if you are deserializing a function which is passed to `eval` - see [here](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/web-security-zone/deserialization-vulnerabilities-attacking-deserialization-in-js/)

Answer (score 2):

Sending `__proto__` out from the server can create a JSON object that may break things if the keys are transferred to another object without removing `__proto__` or leak sensitive data.

It's unusual that it would appear in encoded JSON as it is usually ignored. That suggests there might be a problem or kludge elsewhere. It's possible the library you're using it leaking it by accident or making use of it. It may be alright to make use of it in a closed system but it should not be allowed either into or out of the system.

```
// If is optional.
if('__proto__' in obj)
    // This may cause unintended consequences.
    delete(obj.__proto__);
```

On receiving data you should also be very careful that it doesn't contain a `__proto__` property. This can crash or compromise the server if that key is copied over to another object.

If creating your own object there are tricks to change it's behaviour such as using defineProperty but these tricks tend not to eliminate the problem entirely.

Comment: `delete obj.__proto__` doesn't seem to actually remove it

Answer (score 0):

Just write

`String(<put here your data>)`