# Method is returning __proto__ in a modern browser? How to remove it?

Tags: javascript, prototype

It is a pure-Javascript method returning a simple object,

```
MyClass.retObj = function() {
  return {
    x: {a:1, b:this.b}
    ,y: this.y
  };
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ // ONLOAD:

  console.log( MyClass.retObj().x ) // good...
  console.log( MyClass.retObj() ) // BAD! show __proto__

}, false);  // \ONLOAD
```

Why it returns a `__proto__` in a modern browser?  **How to disable this ugly behaviour in nowadays (2019)**?

MDN says that [this feature "is no longer recommended"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

---

PS: it is [not a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27901443/287948), because here is the simplest and direct context, and I need a simple answer... And it is about "nowadays".

Comment: *"curisilly"* -> *curiously*?

Comment: The rest of it still doesn't make much sense, though. What do you mean *"Who"*, for example? Nobody is required to comment on votes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Comment: It is because all objects have that, always. When enumerating properties you have to ignore the junk ones. Quirky JS thing.

Comment: Hi @MarkMeyer, I edited with `console.log()`, that is whare I see it.

Comment: @trognanders, thanks... I saw few comments about in other sites (perhaps future browser versions take off)... But  are there  no problem? returning an object that is not what I defined? forcing the ingestion of so much rubbish for users of my method? No clean JSON?

Comment: @PeterKrauss If you are asking specifically about Firefox devtools displaying something unexpected, you might want to add a screenshot. And how does it look in other browsers?

Comment: @Bergi, thanks. Well... Modern Firefox shows `<prototype>: {…}`  and modern Chrome shows `__proto__:...`, so both are showing the same `console.log()` output.  As @trognanders say, *"Quirky JS thing"*: it is the best answer.

Comment: @PeterKrauss There's nothing quirky about it, it's just the prototype chain. You cannot avoid it.

Comment: @Bergi, it is like a *spam*, it is **a "non solicited" information** from Javascript parser (seems a *core dump* ugly information of an old compiler).

Comment: @PeterKrauss It is totally useful! It has nothing to do with the parser, it's just the object model. If you have ever `console.log`ged an object with a custom prototype, you're glad you can see this.

Comment: @PeterKrauss JSON.stringify() should *not* include the stuff that should not be there, so at least the JSON would be "clean". The best way to think of it is as an API that should be implemented as an inhereted function, or even better outside of object instances like `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`, but is instead just a regular member value. It will go away someday, but its usage is pervasive enough that too many applications would break.

Comment: @PeterKrauss There are standard API functions to help you filter out the weird extra stuff such as `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` that return just a list of *legitimate* member names that were created on purpose. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why [does it show] a `__proto__`?

The prototype chain is very important if you want to understand why an object behaves in a certain way. Wether it is displayed as `__proto__` or `[[Prototype]]` or `<prototype>` is not really relevant, is it? ...

> How to disable this ugly [object visualization]?

Use another browser if that really bothers you.

> curiously MyClass.retObj().x [does not seem to have] `__proto__`.

Thats indeed fun, probably the console thinks that the Prototype is not relevant to the audience, therefore it hides it, however it isn't really in both cases. On the other hand however this dynamic behaviour of visualizing things is kind of missleading, as one might think that `__proto__` does not exist on one object but the other (it does exist on both).

> MDN says that [`__proto__`] "is no longer recommended".
>   How to disable this ugly [`__proto__` property]?

And I wouldn't recommend using `var`, backwards compability is ugly but mandatory. Removing all those bad design decisions would "break the internet", therefore keeping them is definetly better.

> But are there no problem[s]?

Yes, `__proto__` is problematic to performance optimizations, but ... it's JavaScript, the browsers know how to optimize the uncertain.

> returning an object that is not what I defined?

You also haven't defined `{}.toString()`. If you really need a completely blank object, use

```
 Object.create(null)
```

> forcing the ingestion of so much rubbish for users of my method?

`__proto__` is not enumerable and inherited, you won't find it by accident programmatically if you are not searching for it actively.

> No clean JSON?

```
 JSON.stringify({}) // {} ?!?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks all explanations (!).  Only a bit of comments: `JSON.stringify()` I use only for "external world" of my Javascript code, like in a HTTP output, for internal, I will lost all pre-parsered object.  About `Object.create(null)`, I never used... can you show an example that returns no `__proto__` ?

Comment: @PeterKrauss `Object.create(null)` just has it's internal [[prototype]] set to `null`. There is no object that has no internal prototype link. That all devtools show you the prototype chain for debugging is not a problem. That they use the name `__proto__` to label it is confusing, but not a problem. You are not use the deprecated `__proto__` setter/getter "feature" anywhere.

Comment: Modifying the prototype is optimization poison in V8 at least.

Answer (score 1):

My answer may sound more opinion than fact, but I'll give it a shot. The referenced article, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), states that the use of __ proto __ is not recommended - that is, avoid putting it directly in your code yourself.

That is, don't do this:

```
function Person() {
   this.Name = "";
}
Person.prototype.setName = function(name) {
   this.Name = name;
};
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
   return this.Name;
};

var john = new Person();
console.log( john.__proto__ );
```

Because **proto** has been recommended to be removed from browsers, you shouldn't use it directly in code as future browser updates may remove it entirely, and then your code will break with those updates.